# Slow mail server in looking up host name

Tags: email-server, exim, slow-connection

Hello my mail server is very slow to accept SMTP connections.

I found a tutorial to make a stop in my Exim4 and run the command below to see where it takes.

`exim -bd -d -oX 587`

> Follow the exit, and where is more downtime. Can you help me figure out why it is so slow.

```
29136 Connection request from 187.23.45.188 port 61995
29136 search_tidyup called
29136 1 SMTP accept process running
29136 Listening...
29141 sender_fullhost = [187.23.45.188]
29141 sender_rcvhost = [187.23.45.188]
29141 Process 29141 is handling incoming connection from [187.23.45.188]
29141 host in host_lookup? yes (matched "*")
29141 looking up host name for 187.23.45.188 -----> VERY SLOW HERE
```

Comment: This is EXIM doing a reverse lookup. What DNS servers do you have setup ?

Comment: so I do not know, I just did the installation of "VestaCP" and is the default setting.

Comment: run this command cat /etc/resolv.conf and paste the output

Comment: # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 172.31.0.2
search sa-east-1.compute.internal

Comment: Questions about systems with administrative control panels are [generally off-topic](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3922/question-about-migrated-post-that-was-closed/3924#3924) here at Server Fault.

Comment: Sorry my friend, do not know where you heard me say something about system administration panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'am solved this problem.

I edited a file `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template` and modified this lines:

```
#host_lookup = *
rfc1413_hosts = *
rfc1413_query_timeout = 0s
```